# SQLite INSERT command return error "column number is not unique"

Tags: c++, sql, sqlite

I have a text file with rows (lines). Each row is a record in database table. I read this file and fill database.

Tables creating command:

```
CREATE TABLE gosts(number TEXT PRIMARY KEY, userNumber TEXT, status TEXT, date TEXT, title TEXT, engTitle TEXT, description TEXT, mainCategory INTEGER, category INTEGER, subCategory INTEGER);
```

Inserting query:

```
INSERT INTO gosts VALUES ("30331.8-95", "ÃÎÑÒ 30331.8-95", "Äåéñòâóþùèé", "01.07.1996", "Ýëåêòðîóñòàíîâêè çäàíèé. ×àñòü 4. Òðåáîâàíèÿ ïî îáåñïå÷åíèþ áåçîïàñíîñòè. Îáùèå òðåáîâàíèÿ ïî ïðèìåíåíèþ ìåð çàùèòû äëÿ îáåñïå÷åíèÿ áåçîïàñíîñòè. Òðåáîâàíèÿ ïî ïðèìåíåíèþ ìåð çàùèòû îò ïîðàæåíèÿ ýëåêòðè÷åñêèì òîêîì", "Electrical installations of buildings. Part 4. Protection for safety. Applisation of protective measues for safety. Measures of protection against electric shock", "Íàñòîÿùèé ñòàíäàðò óñòàíàâëèâàåò îáùèå òðåáîâàíèÿ ïî ïðèìåíåíèþ ìåð çàùèòû äëÿ îáåñïå÷åíèÿ áåçîïàñíîñòè è òðåáîâàíèÿ ïî ïðèìåíåíèþ ìåð çàùèòû îò ïîðàæåíèÿ ýëåêòðè÷åñêèì òîêîì ïðè ýêñïëóàòàöèè ýëåêòðîóñòàíîâîê çäàíèé", 37, 333, 628);
```

Please ignore encoding problems. Source file has cp1251 encoding, but inserting sample is taken from console. I tried to use utf-8 but had the same problem.

SQLite using code above:

```
if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, query, -1, &statement, 0) == SQLITE_OK) {
...
}
```

Function calling doesn't return SQLITE_OK. And I gea error message by:

```
string error = sqlite3_errmsg(database);
if(error != "not an error") cout << query << " " << error << endl;
```

Strangely, some records are inserted without error and I can't find differences between good and bad records.

I can provide more information if needed.

Comment: The error "column number is not unique" means that the number value are present in the database (is the primary key), so you cannot insert another row with this number

Comment: But in my case primary key is a text (not a number). Why we discuss a number?

Comment: @MiguelPrz is mentioning 'number' because that is the column that has the non-unique values.  The confusion is coming from the table column named 'number' that is actually of type TEXT.

Comment: yes, it's my mistake in naming. @MiguelPrz, you are right row with the same "number" value already presented in database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would bet that the difference between the good and bad rows were whether or not the value associated with the 'number' column was already in the table.

This is one of the reasons that table designs usually do not use `TEXT` valued columns for `PRIMARY KEY`s.

If it is possible to re-create your table, I would create an ID field responsible for being the `PRIMARY KEY` for your table.  Further enable the `IDENTITY` property for auto increment of your primary key value.

This should prevent insertion failure due to having duplicate values in the 'number' column.

Now if values in 'number' column **must** be unique then you should add a `UNIQUE` constraint on that column.
NOTE: The `UNIQUE` will yield the same error you are currently receiving as it appears you are trying to add multiple rows with the same value for column'number'

Review the [SQLite CREATE TABLE documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. Field "number" might be unique, yes. In my case database is simple and I will not refer to "gosts" entity from another tables. But I'll thinking about "id" field later.